# I want to Load pdf from url and after filling user can download, send email or print document

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, pdfviewer

I want to Load pdf from URL and after filling required fields the user can download, send email or print document from the mobile browser.

I am using Xamarin forms and need a solution for PCL

following is a link that needs to be renders in web view

http://paylesscremation.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/4.-PC-Embalming-NEW.pdf

Comment: "I want" is not an appropriate question for SO.  This is basically an invitation for someone else to do your work for you.  Instead, show us what you've tried to do to solve this yourself, and ask for help solving any *specific* problems you encounter.

Comment: I just want to know is it possible to write pdf document in a mobile browser if so which is the best option to do?